# Excel - assigning to a column a number generated by a condition to reference a cell

Tags: arrays, excel

I am currently trying to write a condition and assign it to column 'b'.

The condition is defining a specific cell, and then putting the number returned in front of the column header. I.e: `=b(COUNT($B$3:B4)*49+48)` (what I have so far, but It doesn't work)

The count returns the value 146, which is what I want, but I need a way to then place that after 'b' so that it becomes `b146` to reference that specific cell.

Answer (score 2):

INDIRECT is Volatile use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(A:A,COUNT($B$3:B4)*49+48)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to utilize a text string as a reference, you'll need to look into working with [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261), which does exactly that. For your case,

```
=INDIRECT("B" & (COUNT($B$3:B4)*49+48))
```

Would get you an indirect reference to column `B`, row number whatever `COUNT($B$3:B4)*49+48)` is returning.